# Spreading UL navigation links horizontally evenly spaced, first link butts up to left edge, last link butts up to right edge

Tags: html, css

There are a lot of versions of this question that Ive looked through and the answers seem to work for the most part but end up cause other issues.

I have a diagram of the layout I'm trying to create here...
[layout diagram](http://i1370.photobucket.com/albums/ag265/arsinek1/web_development/project_1_wireframe_zpskr6i46wi.jpg)

The part I am trying to fix now is the navigation in the top right.

Its 3 links, I want the left link to be on the left edge and the right link to be on the right edge. The middle link will be centered between the left and right link.

One of the issues Ive had with this is when you shrink the size of the window the links stack on top of each other, Id like them to move when you shrink the window but not stack.

Another issue with how I have it now is adding margins or padding on the top to move the links down doesn't work. For some reason its getting ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use flex, use `inline-block` and `text-align:justify`

```css
.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}
li:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}
li:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
ul:after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use flexbox it's easy.

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
  padding:5px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is for a school project. I would want to learn in a way that I could use in a job.

Are many people using flexbox in production?

Comment: depends on your level of browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox. If you need to use IE9 or lower you will probably need to go with my other answer using ``inline-block``

Comment: Are there any sites that display how many people are using IE9 and below?

Comment: yes, google ``browser stats`` and you'll find a bunch. My guess is around 4%. Did either of my solutions work for you?

Comment: I tried the non flexbox one and it didnt work. It sort of does but not completely.

Heres a link... http://www.rhettmoxon.com/project_1/

Comment: I adjusted the solution. check again. You have to set font-size to 0 on the parent.

Comment: No that didnt do it. The problem is I want perfect spacing between the words. Your suggestions adjusts the distribution and size of the li blocks. So the spacing needs to be based off the width of the words. Maybe using an UL isnt the way to go? Or maybe what I want to do just isnt possible? Which seems silly because it seems rather basic.

Comment: Okay, try my example again. There is perfect spacing between the words.

Comment: Here's the issue, word "item 3" needs to be on the right side of the li block or the li block needs to be the exact same size as the words. Right now you have "item 3" on the left side of its block. See how item 1 butts up to the left of its block, I need item 3 to butt up to the right of its block. So it would be item 1 on the left edge, item 3 on the right edge and item 2 sitting exactly between the two. I do appreciate your trying to help. Thanks.

Comment: Oh I think I see. I think you're almost there. I think all you need to do -- if I understand correctly -- is set the ``text-align`` property for each individual list item. So for the one on the far left, it would be ``text-align: left`` and the one in the center it would be ``text-align: center`` and the one on the right would be ``text-align: right``. You can do this by either giving each list item it's own class or using pseudo selectors ``:first-child`` and ``:last-child``

Comment: Thanks bud. I think that pretty much does it. When the browser window allows for 100% width of the site to be shown the links are where they should be and spaced properly. Couple questions, why did you use position relative? Also what does display: inline-block do? And how does the ul:after selector work? Thanks again!

Comment: ``display: inline-block`` used with ``text-align: justify`` allows us to treat a layout like a typography layout. Think about what ``justify`` does -- it evenly distributes all of the words so that they butt up against the left/right edges of container. But, you have to force a line break with ``:after`` otherwise it won't work. Think about how ``justify`` works on the last line of a paragraph. It will not justify the last line. Read more here: http://codeandcolours.com/writes/perfectly-justified-css-grid-technique-using-inline-block/

Comment: and I don't think you need ``relative``